# Using existing mysql database in lampp

Tags: mysql, lamp

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 in a 32 bit machine. I have Windows 8 installed also. I have set up lampp in my ubuntu OS. Now I want to use mysql databases of Windows in ubuntus lampp. I have searched a lot online, but couldn't find any suitable solution. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysqldump.exe` to dump the database contents under Windows into a .sql file. You can then either load it in under Ubuntu by using the `mysql` tool, or you can load it into a separate system so that it is accessible under both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Ss there any way to use same databases? Because I will be using both OS's (windows and ubuntu), so it will be tough to dump databases and import again and again.

Comment: Move the databases to a separate system.

Comment: Can you tell me how? I am using htdocs folder from windows in ubuntu, it is possible. Like that, is it possible to use same mysql databases to use both in ubuntu and windows?

Comment: You should not attempt to share the raw MySQL data files between systems.

Comment: Oh, I understand now...

Comment: What @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams means is to set-up your lamp stack on a separate system. This separate system can be a virtual machine whose files are stored on a partition that is accessible from both your installed operating systems. This way you just boot the preferred OS and run the virtual machine to bring-up your lamp stack. Any change you make is stored in the virtual machine, so when you re-boot to the other OS, just run the vm again and you are set to go.

Comment: Not the whole stack, just the database. It's a lot easier to share PHP files than MySQL databases.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Your point is absolutely correct. I just don't know if it is worth the effort to reconfigure parts of the system just to move the database component on a separate system. It makes more sense to me to move the entire stack on a self contained and autonomous vm. You get a single point for configuration (and also a single point of failure which is one of the disadvantages - but as far as I can tell this is not a concern in the use case here) plus you get maximum portability in case you decide to change development machines.

Answer (score 0):

To create a php development environment in Ubuntu installed with MySQL and Apache, you may try this link :   https://engineersview.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/php-development-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how by heart how to do it, but I know that you can configure MySQL to allow remote connections. By this, you can have your Windows machine run the MySQL server and connect from the virtual Ubuntu over network.